# triple nested for-loops in Json python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, json

i need to print the latitude and longitude from the following python object:

```
{
"Siri": {
"ServiceDelivery": {
  "ResponseTimestamp": "2014-08-09T15:32:13.078-04:00",
  "VehicleMonitoringDelivery": [
    {
      "VehicleActivity": [
        {
          "MonitoredVehicleJourney": {
            "LineRef": "MTA NYCT_B38",
            "DirectionRef": "1",
            "FramedVehicleJourneyRef": {
              "DataFrameRef": "2014-08-09",
              "DatedVehicleJourneyRef": "MTA NYCT_FP_C4-Saturday-090900_B38_110"
            },
            "JourneyPatternRef": "MTA_B380099",
            "PublishedLineName": "B38",
            "OperatorRef": "MTA NYCT",
            "OriginRef": "MTA_504241",
            "DestinationRef": "MTA_901070",
            "DestinationName": "DNTWN BKLYN TILLARY ST",
            "SituationRef": [
              {
                "SituationSimpleRef": "MTA NYCT_78100"
              }
            ],
            "Monitored": true,
            "VehicleLocation": {
              "Longitude": -73.937414,
              "Latitude": 40.692978
            },
```

So far I have written this :

```
for delivery in theJSON['Siri']['ServiceDelivery']['VehicleMonitoringDelivery']:
 for activity in delivery['VehicleActivity']:
    for locations in activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['VehicleLocation']:
        print locations['VehicleLocation']['Longitude']
```

But I am getting error: `typeError:string indices must  be integars.`

How to solve?

Comment: You're iterating over the keys. The keys are strings.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: how to just print the ResponseTimestamp @jonrsharpe

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Follow that link, learn about dictionaries, it's not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['VehicleLocation']` is a dict, not a list, so iterating over it is an iteration over the keys, which are strings. If `locations` is a string, then `locations['VehicleLocation']['Longitude']` makes no sense. You want

```
for delivery in theJSON['Siri']['ServiceDelivery']['VehicleMonitoringDelivery']:
    for activity in delivery['VehicleActivity']:
         print activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['VehicleLocation']['Longitude']
```

Comment: how to just print the ResponseTimestamp